# What cable do I need to connect a DSL modem to my own DSLAM?

Tags: networking, adsl, broadband, adsl-router, dsl-modem

I am a student trying to learn DSL, so I thought the best way was to buy a DSLAM.

I am attempting to connect a DSL modem to a DSLAM, and the DSLAM to a Linux box running PPPoE.

The issue is I am not sure which cables I need for the DSL <--> DSLAM port (I think it might be a RJ-11 to RJ-25?) as usually you plug straight into the telephone jack using a RJ-11 to RJ-11, and then I guess it's copper to the MDF.

Is is possible to connect directly from a DSL modem to the DSLAM, and if so, what cables do I need to buy?

The DSL Modem, for reference sake, is a DLink modem with DD-WRT.

The DSLAM is "ZTE ZXDSL 9806H".

Comment: I assume you have read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line_access_multiplexer)?  As for RJ-11 or RJ-25 entirely depends on your hardware.

Comment: Hi There, yes I've read that and also found an installation manual for the DSLAM link [here](ftp://ftp.vimcom.ru/ZTE/9806H/sjzl20072711.pdf). On pg 4 it shows the shelf structure, with the 'USER' ports on the right. Any idea what cable that would be?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. The cable, for reference sake, is the 50 pin amphenol connector.

It plugs into the RJ-11 port of the DSL modem, and the 50-pin into the DSLAM port